# Adding Css in Spring

Tags: css, spring

I Know this Question may be duplicate but I'm facing a problem. I read all other answers but still not working.

When the page SupplierMenu is loaded it gets its css file (SupplierMenu.css) but it is empty while  I Have written css in it.

This Problem is releated to only this Page while in other pages css is applied to all pages.

this is the picture.it will explain the problem clearly.

http://s10.postimg.org/mhb87tg7d/Untitled.png

It's a dynamic Web Project

and Hierarchy is

this is the pic of Hierarchy

http://s27.postimg.org/q8rqqo7wj/Untitled.png

SupplierMenu.jsp

I am getting Css through this way in jsp.

```
<c:set var="context" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
                               href="${context}/css/SupplierMenu.css"/>
```

SupplierMenu.css

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

 body{
  width: 98%;
  height:630px;
 background: linear-gradient(#eeefef, #ffffff 20%);
}

#menu{
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
margin-left:10px;
height: 100px;
}

.button{
float: left;
margin-left:5px;
margin-top:28px;
}

.button a {
display: block;
height: 50px;
width: 150px;
background: #6f116f;
}

.button a {
display: block;
height: 50px;
width: 200px;
background:  #6f116f;
margin-left:50px;

/*TYPE*/
color: white;
font: 17px/50px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

  }

 p {
  background: #a54143;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 190px; 
  margin: -50px 0 0 10px;
  margin-left:50px;

 /*TYPE*/
text-align: center;
font: 12px/45px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
color: #fff;

/*POSITION*/
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;

/*CSS3*/
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 }

 .button a, p {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);      
 }

.button:hover .top {
 margin: -80px 0 0 10px;
 line-height: 35px;
}

.button:hover .bottom {
margin: -10px 0 0 10px;
}

.button a:active {
 background: #91393c; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #91393c 36%, #009ec3 100%); /* 
 FF3.6+    
 */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-   
 stop(36%,#91393c), color-stop(100%,#009ec3)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #91393c 36%,#009ec3 100%); /* 
 Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #91393c 36%,#009ec3 100%); /* Opera 
 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #91393c 36%,#009ec3 100%); /* IE10+ 
 */
 background: linear-gradient(top,  #91393c 36%,#009ec3 100%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(  
 startColorstr='#91393c',   
 endColorstr='#009ec3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

 }

/*Pulls in Wings*/
 .button:active .bottom {
  margin: -20px 0 0 10px;
 }

  .button:active .top {
   margin: -70px 0 0 10px;
 }

 p {
 background: #a54143;
 display: block;
 height: 40px;
 width: 190px; 
 margin: -50px 0 0 10px;
 margin-left:50px;

/*TYPE*/
text-align: center;
font: 12px/45px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
color: #fff;

/*POSITION*/
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;

/*CSS3*/
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;

-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
 }
```

My Spring Dispatcher Servlet

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-
beans-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context

 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-
            mvc-4.1.xsd">



<context:component-scan base-package="mine.Controllers" />

<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/media/js/" mapping="/js/**" />

<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/media/css/ProductCss/" mapping="/css/**"/> 

<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/media/css/SupplierCss/"
                                                         mapping="/css/**"/> 

 <mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/media/fonts/" mapping="/fonts/**"/> 

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<import resource="xmlSources/ModulesIntegrate.xml" />

<bean id="ViewResolver"

 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>

    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>

  </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: What is your dispatcher servlet mapped to? is it mapped to "/" or some other path? Also please add your location of your css to the post from your war.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `mvc:resources` tag like

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Create resources folder under your src->main->webapp and put all css under resources->css finally use it in jsp

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/SupplierMenu.css">
```

Comment: I have mentioned that this problem occurs only with just this One Css. All others are working Correctly.

Comment: @MuhammadDanishKhanIs this page is the same location like other pages.

Comment: @erhum No you can see it in this photo        http://s10.postimg.org/mhb87tg7d/Untitled.png

Comment: @MuhammadDanishKhanI believe if you try my solution it will be sove your problem, sure you need to create resources folder and under it css folder. And put all the css files in this css folder, then define your mvc:resources in my answer and link it just show my answer.

Comment: Thanks @erhun i just created resources folder under webContent as i am using dynamic web project. and then mapped it. and it worked like a charm. thanks. I accepted your answer.